# Legal to ride bikes on sidewalks in Seattle?

Tags: road-bike, legal

I know in parts of the US it is **illegal** for bicyclists to ride their bikes on the sidwalk.  I've been seeing it a lot in Seattle, WA, US and not sure if it's allowed.

Comment: Legal maybe. But really necessary? It's called a sideWALK for a reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Seattle.gov](http://clerk.seattle.gov/~public/code1.htm):

Section [11.44.120](http://clerk.seattle.gov/~scripts/nph-brs.exe?d=CODE&s1=11.44.120.snum.&Sect5=CODE1&Sect6=HITOFF&l=20&p=1&u=/~public/code1.htm&r=1&f=G) - **Riding on sidewalk or public path**

> Every person operating a bicycle upon any sidewalk or public path shall operate the same in a careful and prudent manner and a rate of speed no greater than is reasonable and proper under the conditions existing at the point of operation, taking into account the amount and character of pedestrian traffic, grade and width of sidewalk or public path, and condition of surface, and shall obey all traffic control devices.  Every person operating a bicycle upon a sidewalk or public path shall yield the right-of-way to any pedestrian thereon, and shall give an audible signal before overtaking and passing any pedestrian.

So I'd say it's legal. Have fun!

Comment: And just as a little extra: its up to you to go in the road, in the bike lane or in the side walk, but you have to adjust to each. (ie if in the road/bike lane, you can cross if green light/stop in red, if in the sidewalk, you'd have to get a walk sign). I'm not exactly sure where it is specified, but I just took the WA driver license test so its fairly fresh in my mind

Comment: I live and breathe this rule everyday as I have to ride sidewalks over bridges... on the sidewalk watch out for people with cell phones, MP3 players, gawkers, and the lost - that's about half the pedestrians these days.

Answer (score 7):

It would seem that cycling on the sidwalk in Seattle is legal:

> **Section 11.44.120 RIDING ON A SIDEWALK OR PUBLIC PATH.**
>   Every person
>   operating a bicycle upon any sidewalk or public path shall operate the
>   same in a careful and prudent manner and a rate of speed no greater
>   than is reasonable and proper under the conditions existing at the
>   point of operation, taking into account the amount and character of
>   pedestrian traffic, grade and width of sidewalk or public path, and
>   condition of surface, and shall obey all traffic control devices. 
>   Every person operating a bicycle upon a sidewalk or public path shall
>   yield the right-of-way to any pedestrian thereon, and shall give an
>   audible signal before overtaking and passing any pedestrian.

-- [Regulations for Bicycling and Driving with Bicyclists](http://www.seattle.gov/transportation/bikecode.htm), Seattle Department of Transportation